# Retrieving value from innerHTML output

Tags: javascript, url, url-rewriting, parse-platform

I know how to retrieve a value from a textfield that a user has inputed, however, I want to be able retrieve the text thats outputed from the following code:

```
  var message =  url;
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = message;
```

Essentially I want to store into Parse a shorten URL, where the URL is generated from the document selected in Google Drive, and then that URL is display on screen to the user, and thats the URL I want to grab to shorten.

Below is the entire code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.parsecdn.com/js/parse-1.2.12.min.js"></script>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>upload</title>

    <script type="text/javascript">

      // The Browser API key obtained from the Google Developers Console.
      var developerKey = 'ID';

      // The Client ID obtained from the Google Developers Console.
      var clientId = 'ID';

      // Scope to use to access user's photos.
      var scope = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/photos'];

      var pickerApiLoaded = false;
      var oauthToken;

      // Use the API Loader script to load google.picker and gapi.auth.
      function onApiLoad() {
        gapi.load('auth', {'callback': onAuthApiLoad});
        gapi.load('picker', {'callback': onPickerApiLoad});
      }

      function onAuthApiLoad() {
        window.gapi.auth.authorize(
            {
              'client_id': clientId,
              'scope': scope,
              'immediate': false
            },
            handleAuthResult);
      }

      function onPickerApiLoad() {
        pickerApiLoaded = true;
        createPicker();
      }

      function handleAuthResult(authResult) {
        if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
          oauthToken = authResult.access_token;
          createPicker();
        }
      }

      // Create and render a Picker object for picking user Photos.
      function createPicker() {
        if (pickerApiLoaded && oauthToken) {
          var picker = new google.picker.PickerBuilder().
              enableFeature(google.picker.Feature.MULTISELECT_ENABLED).
              addView(google.picker.ViewId.PDFS).
              setOAuthToken(oauthToken).
              setDeveloperKey(developerKey).
              setCallback(pickerCallback).
              build();
          picker.setVisible(true);
        }
      }

      // A simple callback implementation.
      function pickerCallback(data) {
        var url = 'nothing';
        if (data[google.picker.Response.ACTION] == google.picker.Action.PICKED) {
          var doc = data[google.picker.Response.DOCUMENTS][0];
          url = doc[google.picker.Document.URL];
                 var message =  url;
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = message;

        }


    var longUrl=message;
    var request = gapi.client.urlshortener.url.insert({
    'resource': {
      'longUrl': longUrl
    }
    });
    request.execute(function(response) 
    {

        if(response.id != null)
        {
            str ="<a href='"+response.id+"'>"+response.id+"</a>";
            document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = str;

              Parse.initialize("ID", "ID");
           var PDFUpload = new Parse.Object("Scan");


     PDFUpload.set("PDFDocument", response.id);

    PDFUpload.save(null, 
     {
        success: function(uploadResult) {
          // Execute any logic that should take place after the object is saved.

        },
        error: function(uploadResult, error) {
          // Execute any logic that should take place if the save fails.
          // error is a Parse.Error with an error code and description.
          alert('Failed to create new object, with error code: ' + error.description);
        }
     });

        }


        else
        {
            alert("error: creating short url");
        }

    });



      }

      function load()
{
    gapi.client.setApiKey('ID'); //get your ownn Browser API KEY
    gapi.client.load('urlshortener', 'v1',function(){});

}
window.onload = load;


    </script>
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js"> </script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="result"></div>
    <div id="demo">
          <div id="output">


    <!-- The Google API Loader script. -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js?onload=onApiLoad"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

In particular, this where I attempt to shorten the URL to store into Parse:

```
var longUrl=message;
    var request = gapi.client.urlshortener.url.insert({
    'resource': {
      'longUrl': longUrl
    }
    });
    request.execute(function(response) 
    {

        if(response.id != null)
        {
            str ="<a href='"+response.id+"'>"+response.id+"</a>";
            document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = str;

              Parse.initialize("ID", "ID");
           var PDFUpload = new Parse.Object("Scan");


     PDFUpload.set("PDFDocument", response.id);

    PDFUpload.save(null, 
     {
        success: function(uploadResult) {
          // Execute any logic that should take place after the object is saved.

        },
        error: function(uploadResult, error) {
          // Execute any logic that should take place if the save fails.
          // error is a Parse.Error with an error code and description.
          alert('Failed to create new object, with error code: ' + error.description);
        }
     });

        }


        else
        {
            alert("error: creating short url");
        }

    });
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Update:
Please try out this code. It shortens a url from the input value you insert. In the sense that you enter example yahoo.ca in the input field, and once you hit convert it shortens it into a url and store in parse. This works succesfully, but I wanted to integrate that into my code where the url is derived from the url that is generated from the item the user has selected from their google drive:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<script src="http://www.parsecdn.com/js/parse-1.2.12.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function makeShort() 
{
   var longUrl=document.getElementById("longurl").value;
    var request = gapi.client.urlshortener.url.insert({
    'resource': {
      'longUrl': longUrl
    }
    });
    request.execute(function(response) 
    {

        if(response.id != null)
        {
            str ="<a href='"+response.id+"'>"+response.id+"</a>";
            document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = str;

              Parse.initialize("ID", "ID");
           var PDFUpload = new Parse.Object("Scan");


     PDFUpload.set("PDFDocument", response.id);

    PDFUpload.save(null, 
     {
        success: function(uploadResult) {
          // Execute any logic that should take place after the object is saved.

        },
        error: function(uploadResult, error) {
          // Execute any logic that should take place if the save fails.
          // error is a Parse.Error with an error code and description.
          alert('Failed to create new object, with error code: ' + error.description);
        }
     });

        }


        else
        {
            alert("error: creating short url");
        }

    });
 }


function load()
{
    gapi.client.setApiKey('ID'); //get your ownn Browser API KEY
    gapi.client.load('urlshortener', 'v1',function(){});

}
window.onload = load;

</script>
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js"> </script>

<body>

URL: <input type="text" id="longurl" name="url" value="yahoo.com" /> <br/>
<input type="button" value="Create Short" onclick="makeShort();" /> <br/> <br/>


<div id="output"></div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why don't you use `var messsage` variable which you are storing into `result` id? Why do you want to get the same content that you are storing in that `result` id?

Comment: Thanks for your response. Could you elaborate? The message variable just return the longurl, which I am then trying to shorten to store the shorten url into parse.

Comment: Why do you want to get text which `<div id="result"></div>` line contain? you are not storing shorten url here. You are storing it into at `<div id="output"></div>`.

Comment: Anyways, if you want to get text from `<div id="result"></div>`, use `document.getElementById('***Id name here***')`. It will give you text within that div tag.

Comment: thanks for your clarification. This line var longUrl=message; is trying to grab the long url that is produced in result, and trying then the following lines are trying to store into parse the shorten url. the div output is suppose to also display the shorten url

Comment: now the other issue is that div id="output" is not being displayed

Comment: thank you for your support and for trying to help me. To clarify the situation, i have added an update under my initial post.